# Can I change command module?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've built a pretty good/enormous first stage rocket that's pretty reliable, and I'd like to use it to put different payloads in orbit. The only problem is I can't seem to switch out my command module. Is there any way to do this, or to save my first stage in such a way that I can import it into different builds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature has been added as of .20.

Editor Improvements

- The Editor no longer requires you to start with a command pod when
  building a ship.
- The Editor now allows deleting or replacing the
  first part of your ship.

[KSP 0.20 Released!](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/showthread.php/30553-KSP-0-20-Released!)

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** this was valid for older versions, see 
ILMTitan's answer for the recent ksp version.

I'd take a look at Payloader:

http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/showthread.php/29950

It lets you combine a payload and a launch vehicle. It works by reading the two craft files and creating a new one, therefore its very non-intrusive (imho).

Comment: Just a note, Payloader doesn't work on 0.19.4 (probably broke with 0.19). Not to knock on it though, it's a good idea and if it worked I would use the hell out of it. But sadly it does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [Subassembly Saver Loader](http://kerbalspaceport.com/subassembly-saver-loader/). Detach everything from the command pod and save those pieces. Then start a new design, select the command pod you want, then use the subassembly plugin to load back in the rest of the design.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not currently possible to swap out the command module you chose when starting your build, at least not using the options available to you in the game.

There are several threads on the Kerbal Space Program forums including a couple of feature requests for exactly this, although I can't provide you any links at the moment due to the KSP forums being down.

Here is a video on YouTube that walks you through editing your saved rockets to achieve a command module replacement in the current version of KSP: